# Tensorflow: completely different results from a same initial guess

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow. I did a simple multivariate regression with the ordinary GD optimization algorithm. However, I got completely different results when two different variable definitions are applied even with a same initial guess.

What is the difference between the two calculations?

When I defined variables with:

```
tau = tf.Variable([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25], name='parameter', dtype=tf.float64)
tau = tf.clip_by_value(tau, 0.1, 5.)
```

I got the result below after 10000 epochs.

`tau= [0.28396885 0.24675105 0.26584612 1.37071573]`

However, when I defined them as normalized values:

```
tau_norm = tf.Variable([0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025], name='parameter', dtype=tf.float64)
tau_norm = tf.clip_by_value(tau_norm, 0.01, 0.5)
tau_max = 10
tau = tau_norm*tau_max
```

I got a completely different result after same 10000 epochs:

`tau= [       nan 0.22451382 2.70862284 1.46199275]`

I expect these two calculations give a same (or similar enough) result because of the same initial guess. However, that was not what I saw. I wonder what causes this difference.

Here, I use tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0, but GPU is not used for this calculation with:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
```

---

#### Updated

Okay, let me explain with an example with the code adapted from [here](https://databricks.com/tensorflow/training-and-convergence). 
I think what I have seen is basically same as below.

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder("float")
y = tf.placeholder("float")
w = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0], name="w")

y_model = tf.multiply(x, w[0]) + w[1]
error = tf.square(y - y_model)
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(error)

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    print("Initial guess: ", session.run(w))
    np.random.seed(seed=100)
    for i in range(1000):
        x_value = np.random.rand()
        y_value = x_value * 2 + 6
        session.run(train_op, feed_dict={x: x_value, y: y_value})

    w_value = session.run(w)
    print("Predicted model: {a:.3f}x + {b:.3f}".format(a=w_value[0], b=w_value[1]))
```

From the code, I got `Predicted model: 2.221x + 5.882`. However, when I replaced `w` with

```
w_norm = tf.Variable([0.5, 1.0], name = 'w_norm')
w = w_norm*2.0
```

the result was `Predicted model: 2.004x + 5.998` even though it has same initial guess (`[1. 2.]`) and same number of epochs. I do not know what makes this difference.

Comment: Hi Sogo, welcome to StackOverflow! In order to make your question easier to answer, it would help a lot if you provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you do that, you can expect an answer quickly :)

Comment: Thank you for your  comment! I will add an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this difference is that `GradientDescentOptimizer.minimize`  will optimize for `tf.Variables`, so your gradient descent won't be applied to the same equation.

Once, you minimise the error `(y - (x*w[0] + w[1])` for the parameters in `w` and the other time you minimise the error `(y - (x*2*w[0] + 2*w[1])` also for `w`.

If in your code you change the learning rate, you algorithm will end up at the same result. To account for the square in the error (taking the square of the norm as the error), if you set 0.04 instead of 0.01 as rate in `train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.04).minimize(error)` you should have the same result.

So:

```py
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder("float")
y = tf.placeholder("float")
w = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0], name="w")

y_model = tf.multiply(x, w[0]) + w[1]
error = tf.square(y - y_model)
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.04).minimize(error)

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    print("Initial guess: ", session.run(w))
    np.random.seed(seed=100)
    for i in range(1000):
        x_value = np.random.rand()
        y_value = x_value * 2 + 6
        session.run(train_op, feed_dict={x: x_value, y: y_value})

    w_value = session.run(w)
    print("Predicted model: {a:.3f}x + {b:.3f}".format(a=w_value[0], b=w_value[1]))
```

prints the same result as

```py
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder("float")
y = tf.placeholder("float")
w_norm = tf.Variable([0.5, 1.0], name = 'w_norm')
w = w_norm*2.0

y_model = tf.multiply(x, w[0]) + w[1]
error = tf.square(y - y_model)
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(error)

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    print("Initial guess: ", session.run(w))
    np.random.seed(seed=100)
    for i in range(1000):
        x_value = np.random.rand()
        y_value = x_value * 2 + 6
        session.run(train_op, feed_dict={x: x_value, y: y_value})

    w_value = session.run(w)
    print("Predicted model: {a:.3f}x + {b:.3f}".format(a=w_value[0], b=w_value[1]))
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood the algo a bit. Basically, the learning rate is multiplied by the gradient of loss function w.r.t. **the variable defined with `tf.Variable`**, and then it is subtracted from the current variable in each epoch. So if you normalize the variable by N, learning rate needs to be N^2 times smaller to obtain the same result. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: In this particular case, yes, the learning rate is multiplied by the gradient in the loss function. The thing to keep in mind is that, as you pointed out, the gradient descent is applied to `tf.Variable`. Having an intermediate variable `x = 2*x_norm` is like having a different model. 
Glad I could help, cheers :)